# Java project won't let me save

Tags: java

Sorry if this question is not suitable for here but I'm going mad trying to sort it out.

I have installed Netbeans and loaded it up to start a project. Once the project was created, I tried to save - but I keep getting an error message saying 'Please select a different file name.'  I have tried only adding in one basic line of working code to see if it will save (it doesn't) and I've tried keeping it as what it populates like, but I keep getting the same message.

I haven't been changing the file name, the file names are obviously anything.java so I am pretty confused here.  if someone could help it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a picture of your project tree?

Comment: Copy out your code into notepad++, save it as a copy, close netbeans and reopen, delete the project from the tree and hard drive. Remake the project and see does it save then.

Answer (score 0):

Update netbeans it had a bug which was resolved [bug details](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=206513)